# Need TableViewCell to blink upon being touched

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a TableViewCell that I want to blink when it's tapped (ie quickly highlight off and on a couple of times).

So far I've implemented this functionality with a timer as follows:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
      NSTimer *blinkTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(toggleHighlightedMenuCell) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
      self.blinkTimer = blinkTimer;
      [blinkTimer release];
} 

-(void) toggleHighlightedMenuCell
{
    if (self.highlightedMenuCell.isHighlighted)
    {
        self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted = YES;        
    }

    self.blinkTimerCounter++;

    if (self.blinkTimerCounter == 2)
    {
        self.blinkTimerCounter = 0;
        [self.blinkTimer invalidate];

        //execute some code
    }
}
```

The problem with this is it seems to start executing the code in the `//execute some code` section before it's finished blinking. Can anyone think of a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: It executes the code before the blinking has finished @rdelmar

Comment: Sorry, I just missed that part of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up chaining some UIView animations together it ended up working perfectly:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.05 delay:0 options:0 animations:
            ^{
                self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted = !self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted;
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:.05 delay:0 options:0 animations:
               ^{
                   self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted = !self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
                {
                    if ([self.menuViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(menuView:didSelectMenuItem:viaTouchType:)])
                    {
                        [self.menuViewDelegate menuView:self didSelectMenuItem:self.highlightedMenuCell.menuItem viaTouchType:TouchTypeTouchUpInside];
                    }
                }];
            }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your time interval is too short to see effectively. I don't think that the "execute some code" is actually being executed until the blinking is over, it just looks like it. There's also no need to do the retain and release statements or assign the timer to a variable. The run loop retains the timer, and releases it when it's invalidated. The selector, though should have a colon after its name, as the timer passes itself as the argument. So the code could be simplified a little to:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(toggleHighlightedMenuCell:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} 

-(void) toggleHighlightedMenuCell:(NSTimer *) aTimer
{
    if (self.highlightedMenuCell.isHighlighted)
    {
        self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        self.highlightedMenuCell.highlighted = YES;        
    }

    self.blinkTimerCounter++;

    if (self.blinkTimerCounter == 2)
    {
        self.blinkTimerCounter = 0;
        [aTimer invalidate];

        //execute some code
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you've initialized blinkTimerCounter somewhere else.